# Query returning single record taking too much time in a EJB-Hibernate Application along with Oracle DB

Tags: oracle, hibernate, ejb, database-administration

I am working with a EJB(3.0)-Hibernate(3) project along with Oracle 11g DB.
First of all due to the security reason I am unable to share my code, I am really sorry for that.
Issue is :
In my Application from different locations, DB has been called for retrieving, persisting, merging records which deals with a number of tables in DB.
But, for a particular retrieve query(select query which is fetching only a single record by putting a primary key data in where clause) from my Application, it is taking too much time(almost 4 minutes) for getting the response from DB(response is proper with a single record).

I can track the time by debugging from calling point to DB inside Application and the retrieving response from DB to my Application.

So, I want to know why for a single record fetching, it is taking so much time where for other queries it's fetching within seconds or micro-seconds.

And also want to know how to track the time-stamp of [query request from Application just hitting the Database after connecting DB through Hibernate Layer] and also what is going on inside the DB for this flow.

Please give me some advice or suggestions from your entire work experience if you facing such kind of issue and also help me how to track the whole flow
Application <-> Hibernate Layer <-> Database

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Have you tried just running your SELECT query at the database level, i.e. via SQL*Plus?  Is the performance the same?  If so, can you or your DBA look at the execution plan for the SELECT query?

Comment: I tried to execute the same query via SQL Developer and there it's taking just some microseconds to get the query-result.